# Modifying dspace discover page in xmlui mirage theme

Tags: css, xslt, dspace

I'm trying to modify the Mirage theme in DSpace 4.2 to cater to the specific needs of my organization. We want to add our own search box with custom search fields, and modify the search results page.

This is how the default dspace search results page looks like:
[image]

After tinkering around with the `css` and `xsl` I came up with this layout:
[image]

The top search panel was added by me by modifying the `page-structure.xsl` file. Now, I want to remove the default search box which appears in the results page. I've looked into all the `css`, `xsl` and `sitemap` files. 
By inspecting the sitemap files I found that the search is carried out by calling the `[dspace-source]/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SimpleSearch.java` file. 
I commented the code sections where the search box was being added, and re-built and re-deployed dspace, but still no success.

Maybe, I'm not looking at the right files, due to lack of understanding.

It would be nice if someone points me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made other modifications to **java** files that were successfully deployed? Did you copy the java files from [dspace-source]/dspace-xmlui to another module? ([dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui would be the right place to copy them to)

Comment: @AntoineSnyers  I haven't made modifications to other java files. Do I need to copy all the java files or just the one I have made changes to?

Comment: Is there any way to disable the search box from the xmap or xslt files without changing the source?

Comment: Just the files that you are modifying. This should be the easiest way.

Comment: @AntoineSnyers Thanks for your help. Sorry if I'm sounding dumb, but can you tell me the exact directory location where the modified files need to be placed. `[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui` contains two directories `src` and `target`. And what is the purpose of copying these files to this particular folder?

Comment: ```dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SimpleSearch.java``` would be copied to ```dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SimpleSearch.java```, it's the same relative path. The "target" directory is deleted and generated by maven every time you ```mvn package``` it.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/tdonohue/making-dspace-xmlui-your-own has more information. But basically by doing the "quick build"  the files in dspace/modules will replace those from the source. Which avoids recompiling the whole source. The tool that does this is the maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the template that generates the search box. In `[dspace]/webapps/xmlui/themes/Mirage/Mirage.xsl` put this after the `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` line:

```
<xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.discovery.SimpleSearch.div.discovery-search-box']">
    <!-- You can also add content here
         to replace the default search box
    -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right path. If you indeed commented out [lines after 131](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/discovery/SimpleSearch.java#L131), you should see the effect that the box is removed.

So if you are not seeing the change, it's possible that there is something wrong with how you deploy these updates. Can you confirm that you have performed a mvn clean package and ant update before restarting your tomcat?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Bram. I actually did comment out the lines which you pointed out, and I did perform a mvn clean package and ant update. I followed this link for rebuilding and deploying the updates (https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Rebuild+DSpace#RebuildDSpace-QuickRestart%28Justrestartsthewebserverafterconfigurationchanges*%29). I also cleaned out the localhost folder of tomcat. And the new updates did get deployed because my dspace reverted back to the default Mirage theme.